# Finding power series representation of functions

Tags: power-series

I was wondering how to find the power series representation of

$$sinh(x) = \frac{{e^x}-{e^{-x}}}{2}$$ in sigma notation.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the power series for $e^x$?

Comment: @saulspatz yes it is $$\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comment: So then, what is the power series for $e^{-x}$?  Wait.  You mean $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {x^k\over k!}$

Comment: @saulspatz it is $$\frac{-x^k}{k!}$$ but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Yes I meant the sum sorry @saulspatz

Comment: You need to be more careful with your notation: $-x^k\ne(-x)^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^x=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...+\frac{x^k}{k!}+....ad-inf ~~(1)$$
And
$$e^{-x}=1-\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+...+(-1)^k\frac{x^k}{k!}+....ad-inf ~~~(2)$$
Suntracting (2) from (1) you get
$$\sinh x =\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=x+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+...\frac{x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}+....ad-inf ~~~(3)$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {x^k\over k!}$$ when we substitute $-x$ for $x$ we get $$e^{-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {(-x)^k\over k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {(-1)^kx^k\over k!}$$  (You were careless with this in your comment.)  Now, $$e^x-e^{-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1-(-1)^k\over k!}x^k$$ by term-by-term addition.

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: do you simply multiply $$e^x-e^{-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1-(-1)^k\over k!}x^k$$ by 1/2 and get the answer? @saulspatz

Comment: @Alex.G Not quite.  Multiplying by $\frac12$ gives the answer, but you want to simplify $1-(-1)^k$ also.  What is the value when $k$ is even?  What is the value when $k$ is odd?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special way to do it with complex number.

As $\sinh z=-i\sin(iz)$,
$$\sinh z=-i\sin(iz)=-i\left[(iz)-\dfrac{(iz)^3}{3!}+\dfrac{(iz)^5}{5!}+\cdots\right]=z+\dfrac{z^3}{3!}+\dfrac{z^5}{5!}+\cdots$$